# How to remove all selection from all registered layers using QGIS plugin?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I want to remove all selection from registered layer in QGIS using Python. I tried to clear the map canvas using:

```
self.iface.mapCanvas().clear()  
self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

but the selection persists.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is probably a better way to do this, but you can iterate the layers in mapCanvas, and use [removeSelection()](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#acedacb37761e05ab82e068d693959c86) method.

Something like this:

```
mc = self.iface.mapCanvas()

For layer in mc.layers():
    if layer.type() == layer.VectorLayer:
        layer.removeSelection()

mc.refresh()
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a another method is given below:

```
for a in iface.attributesToolBar().actions(): 
  if a.objectName() == 'mActionDeselectAll':
    a.trigger()
    break
```

Comment: Deselects all the selected features (from different layers) at once. No need for iterating the map layers.

Answer (score 1):

`iface.mainWindow().findChild(QAction, 'mActionDeselectAll').trigger()` works also.