# How to Unselect Features with QGIS tool "selectbyexpression' and the ">" Operator

Tags: qgis, python

First of all I've successfully used the "selectbyexpression" tool to UN-SELECT points by setting its 3rd parameter to "2" in the following script:

```
Input = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('Central_Region_civic_pts')[0]
clear_expression = '"STRNAME" = '+"'"+"Main"+"'"
processing.runalg('qgis:selectbyexpression', Input, clear_expression, 2)
```

But now I want to write an expression that will unselect EVERYTHING, not just a particular street by name (e.g. "MAIN").  This will be useful near the start of my script to wipe the slate clean, just in case anything is already selected, before my script goes on to make the selections I actually want.

Since my 'Input' file has a "PID" column ("Property ID", all numbers) I figured something like the following would work:

```
clear_expression = '"PID" > 0'
```

But it doesn't.

---

QUESTION

I suspect the problem is with the ">" symbol.  Can anyone confirm this, and suggest a workaround or another tool to do the job?

---

I also suspect there's nothing unique about the ">" symbol.  I'll bet there are more operator symbols than ">" that also don't work with this tool because the "Select By Expression" GUI at the top menu of QGIS only has 9 operator options at the top and ">" isn't one of them.  Neither is "<".  And there's no option for "does not equal" either, etc, etc...

[image]

Comment: In SQL, `<>` means "does not equal" - see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: Yes, useful in SQL.  Unfortunately doesn't appear to be an option in QGIS's "selectbyexpression" GUI or by scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this, where `Input` is your layer object?

```
Input.removeSelection()
```

see: [How to remove all selection from all registered layers using QGIS plugin?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82319/how-to-remove-all-selection-from-all-registered-layers-using-qgis-plugin)

Comment: Thanks @pauloraposo, this proves to be the most elegant solution so far!

Answer (score 1):

Could you do a 'create new selection' that chooses to select something that will definitely result in zero results?

Comment: I certainly could @Koshy Thomas.  That did the trick, thanks loads!  Too bad Q doesn't have more operators available but perhaps in future versions.